# Serving secure cookies to http traffic in Django web app

Tags: django, cookies

In Django, if I set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True`,  it ensures only secure cookies are sent over https.

Now my Django web project serves traffic over **both** `http` and `https`. If I set the aforementioned flags, will it cause any problems for traffic over `http`? Or that traffic will continue to be served normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings tell the browser not to send `session` and `csrf` cookies over `http`. So you won't be able to submit forms (unless you explicitly bypass csrf check) and you won't be able to use sessions over `http`. This is the goal of these settings.

Comment: Hmm, so in an application where data is sent both over `http` and `https`, it's advisable not to turn that on eh? Fair enough, I'll mark this answer. Btw any idea whether setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` will have a deleterious effect in my set up too?

Comment: If the pages you serve through HTTP do not need to POST forms nor use sessions, you can safely set this setting to `True`. Are you serving the same pages either through HTTP or HTTPS? If so, do you have any reason to do this rather than redirecting all HTTP request to HTTPS?

Comment: About `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`, why do you want to set it? Do you use a proxy that sets this header? Do you have issues with requests not considered secured while they should be or vice versa?

Comment: Well I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy, though I do have the line `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` under the relevant server block for `https`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you set this header. Is the request forwarded over HTTP even if it was over HTTPS? But yes, you can set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` to this value if this is the way you determine wheter the request is secure or not.